# Reset yAxis Min and Max on drilldown

Tags: highcharts

I have seen similar questions just like these (even with similar title) but none of them provide the answer I need.

I have a [bar-negative-stack](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-negative-stack) chart with drilldown. 
In order to keep the Y-axis centered, I am calculating the maximum value among the series and setting it as the extremes of the chart.

The thing is I haven't find a good place to put this logic. I have tried putting it on `redraw` or `render` events but, since I am changing the yAxis, this causes a stackoverflow. 
What I have so far that is more or less working is having the `drilldown` event set up with a `setTimeout` to delay the calculation, otherwise it would get the values before the drilldown. I would need some event like `drilldownFinish`.

Here's a working fiddle with this drilldown logic (not on negative-bar-stack though): http://jsfiddle.net/6qpq78do/

Any ideas on how to do this without a `setTimeout`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maximum callstack exceeded message is caused by `setExtremes` function. Its third argument is `redraw` - it's `true` by default: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#setExtremes

So `setExtremes` will call the `redraw` event again and the `redraw` event will call `setExtremes` and so on...

The **solution** here is to create a flag (`redrawEnbaled`) that is going to control the access to the logic placed in `redrawEvent` and prevent this infinite recursive loop:

```
var redrawEnabled = true;
(...)
events: {
  redraw: function() {

    if (redrawEnabled) {
      redrawEnabled = false;
      let values = [];

      this.series.forEach(s => {
        s.yData.forEach(v => values.push(Math.abs(v)));
      });
      let max = values.reduce((acc, val) => (acc > val) ? acc : val, 0);

      this.yAxis[0].setExtremes(-max, max);

      redrawEnabled = true;
    }

  }
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zjuy21k5/